# listing the files in a current directory with same permission

Tags: shell, unix

I need to Write a Unix shell script  that accepts two or more arguments, a file mode, a command and an optional list of parameters and performs the given command with the optional parameters on all files with that given mode.

For example, `mycode 644 ls -l` should perform the command ls -l on all files in the current directory that have mode 644.

I use this code to change the file permission to numeric mode

```
#!/bin/sh
 mode=$1
 #it adds the numeric permission to the beginning of the line
 ls -l |awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
         *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print }'
 .....
 shift $1
 $*
```

but I dont know how to ask the code to list only files with same permissions. how can I ask the code to do it?

Comment: What should happen if no files in the current dir match the given mode?

Comment: it is the last question. =)) normally it should display an error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `find` command for this. E.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -perm 644 -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

Comment: is there any other option rather than using find?

Comment: @femchi: loads of them, but none that are easy and reliable.

Comment: I'm a student not a pro and now looking for basics. would you offer me some basic ones or any article that I can work on it and get some knowledge about the issu

Comment: @femchi: well, if you want to do it the hard way, then transforming the permissions to the kind output by `ls -l` and then grepping the output of that might be worth a try. But in practice, `find` is just the right tool for this.

Comment: thank you. It is a student project and I need to stay in their boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you use one more awk like this. Here i am taking first columns where 644 is available. this way you don't have to use find command.Instead of 644 you can put any variable & pass the argument with required permission & list those files as per input.

```
ls -l |awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
         *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print }' | awk '$1 ~ 644'
```